# "dojo is undefined" in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo

> I created a site using ning, when i
>   open the site in IE, I get an error
>   "dojo is undefined". The page display
>   is totally haywire. But the site works
>   perfectly in other browsers (i have
>   tried in safari only).
>
> I am looking for some workaround / fix
>   on the server side, since i do not
>   expect users to change their IE
>   parameters
>
> Thanks

Comment: You can install the [developer toolbar in IE](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359) to troubleshoot script issues.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some more specifics? This may have several reasons. Sounds like there was some syntax error like a trailing comma or alike. But a bit more input may help, or a link.

Comment: Thanks for the response. the link to the site is http://www.firstballsix.com. The version of IE where I see the error is 6.0.2900.2180.xpsp2.

Do you need any other information ?

Comment: One more point I wanted to add, if I reload the page in IE some 5 or 6 times, the problem just goes away (the pageloads properly) But the problem would recur for some links again, and will occur again if I open IE again -

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try looking at your site with Fiddler2 (www.fiddler2.com) running to see if one of your script URLs is broken.

For instance, you've got a reference 404'ing right now...

GET http://track.ning.com/2?v=BazelCSPerfLite,xdate,sorkutjunior,xhost,xip,xua,snull,xpath,4Ya,4Hl,4IG,4Eq,4Bf,4U,4f,40,40,,4D,4D,,,shomepage&r=182822774

404 Not Found